# Automate import of multiple .txt files from same directory into one table on microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, import, automation, load

Can anyone help me with the best/easiest way to continuously(once a day) import multiple .txt files from same directory into one table on microsoft sql server. Is it possible to set this up via SSMS??

All the files are of the same format.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with SSIS.   The `ForEachLoop` task can be used to iterate through the files in the folder.   Since they all are going into the same table, I assume they all have the same structure, so a single `DataFlowTask` in the `ForEachLoop` should be sufficient.

Comment: I work for a large corporation, so it would be easier for me to run a job in MSSM, than get access to use SSIS.

Comment: What is MSSM?   Do you mean SSMS?

Comment: Yes I mean SSMS.

Comment: I don't know any way to do this only in SSMS.   Maybe OSQL, I've never used it.  You'd need to write some application for iterating through the files and calling some form of bulk insert in whatever language you prefer and call that application from a job.

Comment: If you are allowed access to "xp_cmdshell" then you can use file system commands to get a directory listing and use bcp to import the .txt files